# Can't ping outside IP address

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-catalyst

Our firewall is Cisco ASA and our switch catalyst 2960.

One computer keeps having the following problem :

- Once for a while (in one or two days), the computer can't ping outside IP address like 4.2.2.2 and 8.8.8.8. The computer can ping inside network resources such as printers and servers.
- When this occurs, the computer can't access the internet.
- Renewing IP doesn't fix the problem. We must change it to the static IP adders to make it work again. However, the problem comes back in a couple hours.
- We have replaced the computer and make sure the NIC driver is up to date. We even changed the switch port connecting to the computer.

What could be the problem?

Comment: How is this a problem? Why do you care if the computer can  ping outside addresses? What's the real problem?

Comment: What can show the `traceroute`?

Comment: Because it can't access to the Internet. Now, I find more and more computers have this issue. When that happens, the computer can't access the Internet and we can't ping ASA inside. Tracert is all timeout.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: How many computers do you have on the subnet?  Is it possible you're running out of addresses?   When a computer can't reach the internet, what IP address does it have?

Answer (score 1):

If you have more and more computer having this issue, and configuring static IP solves the problem, have a look at dhcp configuration.

If the network range configured in dhcp is /24 and you start having more than 252 computers, you are likely to have trouble.